# SSMS: Expand one database, without leaving all Databases expanded

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm working on a platform with an over-the-top (HUGE) number of objects.  On tables, views, stored procedures and most objects I can put a Filter which helps.

However, on many servers, this particular company has even a ridiculously huge number of databases.  So much so that it ALWAYS takes up 100+% of the vertical space on my screen.

Is there any way to Filter databases, or (by any technique), simply end up with ONE database 'expanded', but NOT "Database**s**" expanded?

Comment: Do you need to see all those other databases?  If your login has the appropriate rights(not too many), you should only see the databases you need to.  If there is only one database you need to work with, I'd limit your rights to just that database or create a separate login just for the one you are working on.

Comment: I am not the DBA (just a lowly developer), but so I guess to implement your suggestion I would need to ask the DBA to limit my account and get rid of those many DB's I don't need (you're correct I don't need most of them).  Does that sound right?  Or can I use some session-specific command to get rid of them from view?

Comment: That sounds right.  I'd just have them give you db_owner(or least amount you need) to your one database.

Comment: OK thank you.  I'm not sure what the protocol is in this situation, but "thanks" to you and I've marked the other thing as an answer, although your additional dialogue has helped me as well.  Wish SO had more of a forum-type layout.  The need to dialogue via comments (technically discouraged), is silly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <username>`
And to view all databases `GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <username>`

username being the username you connected with. I would suggest not logging on with a SYSADMIN account. See [this link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2995/how-to-hide-sql-server-user-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio/) for details.